# Is VS Code any help in installing a CMake-based library?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I have a library from GitHub that has a simple cmake-based installation. Does VS Code offer me any help in installing that and using it in my project? There is no extension for this library, so it needs to be installed somehow. Is that by me, outside of VS Code, or is there an easier way?

Comment: ***Does VSCode offer me any help in installing that and using it in my project?*** No. It's not involved in any way in the install process of a library. Install it using CMake then setup your code to use the installed library.

Comment: ***using it in my project?*** There is the [CMakeTools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) that you will use with VSCode to support your CMake based project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the CMake Tools extension offering any such feature to help with installation of libraries, and I think that's reasonable. There are several ways to "install" CMake-supporting libraries and depend upon them. Some projects may support (through [`export()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html)) [`include()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html)ing the targets from the build directory of the library, you can build it and then [`cmake --install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project) (and where you want to install is intentionally up to you, though there are platform-specific default installation locations) and then [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#command:find_package), or [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html), or git submodule and [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html). See also [the official "Using Dependencies Guide"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/using-dependencies/index.html).

Each of those options depends on whether the library supports that method of installation (not everything supports everything. consult your library's installation documentation), and can require you to make changes to your project's configuration to depend upon that library in the way that you choose. Ultimately, this is up to your project's CMake configuration and/or the way that you invoke CMake to generate a buildsystem for your project and not really to VS Code.